# Point Load Balancer at new Server

Tags: load-balancing, azure, azure-networking

This has landed on my doorstep.

I've been directed here having asked this question on the wrong board.

We have a test SP2016 environment in Azure. It's current VM set up is 1 App (Web01) , 1 DB (DB01) server.

They have added a new App Server (Web02) and a new DB server (DB02) and want to test it. I've been asked to point the existing Load Balancer in azure at Web02 exclusively. It is currently pointing to Web01 exclusively. Then fail over the DB so DB02 is Primary. I can failover the DB, it's the load balancing I'm struggling with.

The person who set this up has left and I've been tasked with doing this. It's fair to say my Azure/Load Balancing knowledge is .......... close to Zero.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.Thanks

Dan

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using the Azure LB, then all you have to do is to remove Web01 from the Backend Pool of the LB and Add Web02. You can do this through the portal interface. Once you've completed the test, make sure to add it back to the pool. Here's an example for a SQL Cluster, but the steps are the same for a web frontend:

[image]

You can also update the LB with Powershell as in the following link:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/load-balancer/load-balancer-get-started-ilb-arm-ps#update-an-existing-load-balancer

Another simple way of testing the LB is to simply shut down or stop the services in one of the VMs, that will make the LB redirect the traffic to the healthy virtual machine only.

Make sure you understand the Azure Architecture behind this by reading the following article:

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/reference-architectures/sharepoint/

Comment: Thanks Bruno - Clear and concise and exactly what I needed.